# How to process XMLmessage in spark streaming and kafka?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am new to spark. Consuming message from kafka as xml format in spark streaming. Can you tell me how to process this xml is spark streaming?

Answer (score 0):

Spark Streaming and Kafka documentation is available upstream with examples:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-8-integration.html

Here's the compatibility matrix for versions supported. Stick to the stable releases first since you're getting started with streaming:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html

You could use this library to process XML records from Spark.
https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml